# Fetch() GET request in reactjs throwing error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

```js
 import React, { Component } from 'react'


export default class Games extends Component {
state ={
    loading: true,
    
    
    
}
   async componentDidMount(){
   
    const url="https://api.steampowered.com/ISteamApps/GetAppList/v0001/";
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const data= await response.json();
    this.setState({game: data.applist[0],loading:false});
    
}
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            {this.state.loading||!this.state.game?(<div>loading...</div> ):(
            <div>
                <div>{this.state.game.appid}</div>
                <div>{this.state.game.name}</div>
            </div>)}
        </div>
    );
}
}
```

Access to fetch at 'https://api.steampowered.com/ISteamApps/GetAppList/v0001/' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
Games.js:14 GET https://api.steampowered.com/ISteamApps/GetAppList/v0001/ net::ERR_FAILED

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't a react specific bug. Let me explain what's happening here.

Simplified explanation to CORS: (more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS))

CORS is the mechanism which allows the server to send a response back for an api (in your case `url=https://api.steampowered.com/ISteamApps/GetAppList/v0001/`) only when the request is coming from a specific domain/origin.

For example using *`CORS` we can allow server to respond only to API Requests made from [www.steampowered.com](http://www.steampowered.com) origin. (and not localhost and other origins)*

Now coming to:

> If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled

This means that you can still get the response but of type `opaque`.
Run this and see the response:

```js
async function apiCall() {
    const url = 'https://api.steampowered.com/ISteamApps/GetAppList/v0001/'
    const response = await fetch(url, {
        mode: 'no-cors',
    })
    console.log(response)
}

try {
    apiCall()
} catch (e) {
    console.log('Err is', e.message)
}
```

From [developers.google.com](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/03/introduction-to-fetch):

> An opaque response is for a request made for a resource on a different origin that doesn't return CORS headers. With an opaque response we won't be able to read the data returned or view the status of the request, meaning we can't check if the request was successful or not.

You can use proxies to bypass this. Although if you own the aforementioned url, you can configure to grant yourself the necessary access.

Comment: I can't cach the data this way and I get this error :Unhandled Rejection (SyntaxError): Unexpected end of input

Comment: Yes you can't. That's the point of CORS @AliSezerYılmaz.
CORS is making sure that only certain domains/origin get access.